# Why SVG inside DIV aligns different from SVG in BUTTON element

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG element inside a DIV and a BUTTON element. In the button it's aligned both vertical and horizontal center, and in the DIV it is aligned top and left.

I've inspected both elements but could not find what makes the SVG align middle in BUTTON. There must be something in the user agent stylesheet but I could not find it.

```css
button,
div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 8px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: transparent;
}

button svg,
div svg {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M21.99 4c0-1.1-.89-2-1.99-2h-16c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14l4 4-.01-18z"></path>
            <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M21.99 4c0-1.1-.89-2-1.99-2h-16c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14l4 4-.01-18z"></path>
            <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"></path>
        </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Because the content used on buttons is always centred (Replace the image with text, and you'll see it's always centred, because that's the natural behaviour and appearance of a button).

Comment: It is probably defined in the speck but I want to know what is under the hood. What CSS actually makes the behavior. Inspectors do not give me that info

Comment: Partial info: `padding:0px` and `text-align: left` will change the horizontal center alignment. In chrome, these are set by default ( you can check in styles list )

Comment: I don't think it's CSS at all, I think it's something built into the framework of HTML and how it works. Besides, your question isn't even really a question.

Comment: That is only for the horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the button in your browser's dev tools, you will be able to see the user-agent CSS rules that the browser applies by default to elements like button (you might need to enable this option).  For instance, in Chrome you will find a `text-align: center` amongst the CSS properties for `<button>`.  However, since vertical centering of one element inside another is not something that can be done with the standard CSS box of tricks, you won't find any property to do that.  AFAIK it is a special thing that the browser does for buttons.

There are tricks that allow you to do it, such as using `display: table-cell;`, but, in your case, the easiest solution is to get the SVG engine to do it for you.  Just use `text-align: center` to do the horizontal centering, and set the SVG height to the `<div>` height and the the SVG engine will do the rest.

```
button, div {
    ...
    text-align: center;
}

div svg {
    height: 44px;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/eoyx659n/5/)

Comment: "vertical centering of one element inside another is not something that can be done with the standard CSS box of tricks". This is no longer correct.

Answer (score 0):

The top left positioning you see in `<div>` is what you should reasonably expect.

HTML `<button>` elements have an idiosyncratic display which leads their content to be centered horizontally and vertically. There's no way you could know this without learning it as an exception - it's just an unusual display feature, natively integrated into HTML.

If you want to recreate the horizontal and vertical centering in the `<div>` element, you can apply the following styles to the `<div>`:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**N.B.** You can use `display: flex | flex block | flex inline` - the two word syntax is newer.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: transparent;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


div {
  display: flex inline;
  justify-content: center; /* aligns horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* aligns vertically */
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: transparent;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M21.99 4c0-1.1-.89-2-1.99-2h-16c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14l4 4-.01-18z" />
    <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"></path>
  </svg>
</button>

<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M21.99 4c0-1.1-.89-2-1.99-2h-16c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14l4 4-.01-18z"></path>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```